# Reactjs: putting two useState value as output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that takes a user input (strings) and convert each letters into numbers then returns the sum of them. I also have another function that checks if the sum is prime or not.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [result, setResult] = useState([])
    const [prime, setPrime] = useState([])
    
    function getData(val) {
        let value = val.target.value
        value = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, '')
        setData(value)
        console.warn(value)
    }


    function calculate() {
        var result = 0
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            result += data[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96
        }
        setResult(result)
    }

    function isPrime() {
        var prime = ''
        for (var i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(result); i<s; i++) {
            if (result % i == 0 || result <= 1) {
                prime = ' which is not a prime number'
            } else  {
                prime = ' which is a prime number'
            }
        }
        setPrime(prime)
    }

    function finalOutput() {
        calculate()
        isPrime()
    }
```

I have a button with the onClick event (finalOutput) but useState prime doesn't seem to show up on my webpage.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Input Letters" className="footer-input" onChange={getData} />
    <Button type="button" onClick={finalOutput}>Calculate</Button>
</form>

<p>{result}{prime}</p>
```

Comment: Do both of the calculations in the same function call

Comment: You can call `isPrime(result)` in your `calculate()` method after setResult. That way you know it will use the calculated result. Or use a useEffect with `result` as dependency. Also, do not initialize result and prime as empty array;s `[]` if they are number and string respectively

Comment: I have changed my code so that both calculations are in the same function call. but for results in range of 1-5, nothing is being returned. And "which is not a prime number" does not get printed at all

Comment: can you update the code in your question to the new code you have ? Also please check ( with debugger or console.log ) if `s` is greater than 2

Comment: I have updated the code using useEffect

Comment: Are you wanting to have the same numerical value for both upper case and smaller case letters? E.g. Do you want 'A' and 'a' to have same values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've understood, your input takes only alphabetic characters (both upper case and lower case), but not numbers. And, when you click on the calculate button, you'd want the result in numeric format (by converting alphabets into their corresponding numeric values).
You can firstly begin by changing the states to hold the correct initial values, since, the values `result` and `prime` hold a number and a string in the end, it'd make more sense to have their initial states be `null` and `''` or `0` and `''`.

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null) //Null, if you are rendering the initial value on the screen
    const [prime, setPrime] = useState('') //Empty string
```

In your `getData` function, you are not correctly appending values on the state array on each keystroke. The correct and good way to append values to the array would be to use the spread operator(`...`), you can get hold of the previous values and append the newly received value to the array. Also, make sure you don't append empty string values to the array, because `charCodeAt(0)` for an empty string returns `NaN`.

```
function getData(val) {
        let value = val.target.value.trim()
        value = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, '')
        if(value!==''){
           setData(prev=>[...prev,value]) //Appending new value using spread operator
        }
        console.warn(value)
}
```

Further, you'd want to call `isPrime` in your `calculate` function, as setting the state is asynchronous process and you wouldn't able to capture the set value immediately right after. Update your `isPrime` function to accept the result as an argument.

```
function calculate() {
        var result = 0
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            result += data[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96
        }
        setResult(result)
        isPrime(result)
}
```

Coming to the `isPrime` function, it looks alright. Now that, `finalOutput` function isn't used, you could instead make the button click listener point to the `calculate` function. Altogether, your component should look, something like this:

```
export default function Component(){
 const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
    const [prime, setPrime] = useState('')
    
    function getData(val) {
        let value = val.target.value
        value = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, '')
        // console.log(value)
        setData(prev=>[...prev,value])
        // console.warn(value)
    }


    function calculate() {
        var result = 0
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            result += data[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96
        }
        // console.log(result)
        setResult(result)
        isPrime(result)
    }

    function isPrime(res) {

      
        var prime = ''
        for (var i = 2;,s = Math.sqrt(result);i<=s; i++) {
            if (res % i === 0 || res <= 1) {
                prime = ' which is not a prime number'
            } else  {
                prime = ' which is a prime number'
            }
        }
        setPrime(prime)
    }

    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
         <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Input Letters" className="footer-input" onChange={getData} />
         <button onClick={calculate}>Calculate</button>
      </form>

     <p>{result}{prime}</p>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because setResult works asynchronously. So the result state used in isPrime function does not have the value yet as this function is executed immediately. Therefore an empty string is being set in setPrime.

For the solution you can use useEffect like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    // check if result is empty
    if (result.length !== 0) {
      isPrime();
    }
  }, [result]);
```

In the above code useEffect runs when result state changes and inside the useEffect, isPrime function is called when result is not empty.

There are other ways too like using promises but I think this should do it.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed updated my code using useEffect but this time nothing is getting printed

Comment: can you put `let` infront of `prime` inside of `outputPrime()` function and the if condition inside useEffect should be `if(result !== null)`.